# Using the node-robosmart calls

Tags: node.js, bluetooth

I have been using the code from github sandeepmistry/node-robosmart.  Specifically I am doing this:

```
var async = require('async');
var RoboSmart = require('./index');
var found =0;
RoboSmart.discover(function(roboSmart) { 
async.series([
function(callback) {
  console.log('connect');
  roboSmart.connect(callback);
},
function(callback) {
  console.log('discoverServicesAndCharacteristics');
  roboSmart.discoverServicesAndCharacteristics(callback);
},
function(callback) {
  roboSmart.getLightName(function(lightName) {
    console.log('light name = ' + lightName);
    if(lightName = 'XXXX'){
    found=1;
    console.log(found);
    }
    callback();
  });
},
function(callback) {
  console.log('disconnect');
  roboSmart.disconnect(callback);
}
],
function() {
  process.exit(0);
});
});
```

The code works great and I am able to do other stuff.  What I am having trouble with is using the RoboSmart.discoverAll(timeout, callback(devices)); // Returns array of devices discovered within  command.

When I use this code:

```
var async = require('async');
var RoboSmart = require('./index');
var found =0;
RoboSmart.discoverAll(2000,function(devices) {
  async.series([
  function(callback) {
  }
],
function() {
process.exit(0);
});
});
```

~
It Hangs.  Can someone help me with using this function?

Comment: You are not calling calback() inside the first function of async.series and if you only want to call process.exit(0) the remove async.series(...) completely

Comment: Thanks. I added the callback and now I can get the devices back